# apply reduce on a list with partial function python

Tags: python, reduce, partial

I have a list:

```
ll = [1,2,3]
```

I have a function:

```
def hello(x, v):
    x[v] = True
    return x
```

I have an iterable `ii = [1,2]`

Currently, I do:

```
for i in ii:
    ll = hello(x=ll, v=i)
```

How to do this with reduce and partial?

EDIT:
I solved it with:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: hello(x,y), ii, ll)
```

Comment: BTW, `hello` mutates `x`. Anyway, why do you need `reduce`? `reduce`, as the name suggests, is designed to reduce a list into a single value (or operations similar to that).

Comment: @iz_ Despite the name, `reduce` really just consumes the values of a list to produce a new value (which could also be a list).

Comment: `lambda x, y: hello(x,y)` just adds an extra function call you don't need; it's equivalent to `hello` itself. Pass `hello` directly to `reduce` as the first argument.

Comment: @chepner Yes, you're right; I was getting confused :)

Comment: @chepner nice one. thank you